# Which sentence is correct and why? (1)

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> **a** - There will be an employment fair held tomorrow.
>
> **b** - An employment fair will be held tomorrow.

*IF (a) is correct, kindly explain the structure of the sentence. Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think one of them is wrong?

Comment: Does the (1) mean that there are more of these to come?

Comment: No. (a) means there will be a fair tomorrow (only)

Comment: I just thought (a) sounds a bit unnatural. If I put "to be" in (a) like this: "There will be an employment fair TO BE held tomorrow." it will sound wrong. So I asked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence a. is correct, but *held* is redundant. We don't normally say:

> There will be a presentation *given* tomorrow.
>
> There will be a rehearsal *performed* on Friday.
>
> There will be match *played* next weekend.

The first sentence follows the usual [Given-New](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Given-Before-New-Principle.htm) pattern of placing new information towards the end of the sentence. This is why the first of the following pairs is more usual:

> There is a cat on the roof. / A cat is on the roof.
>
> There was a fly in my soup. / A fly was in my soup.

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical.

(a) uses the device known as existential **there**. It is used, in the words of the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’:

> . . . to state the existence or occurrence of something . . . The noun
>   phrase following *be* is called the **notional subject** . . . Clauses
>   with existential *there* are called existential clauses. The main
>   function of existential clauses is to introduce new information.

(b) is a passive construction and follows the normal English word order of Subject (‘an employment fair’) followed by Verb (‘will be held’).